# Solving equation with lists and functions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is as follows:

[image: This is the question]

Users needs to input 3 numbers within the lists and according to the numbers entered, you need to put them in the equation and get the result (with using functions for equation). In the last part ı wanted to show full equation and result together

equation right here   **q = ((2 * n1 * n2) / (n3) ** 1 / 2)**

I did this

```
def sum (myList=[]):
for x in myList:
    q = float(((2 * myList[0] * myList[1]) / myList[3]) ** 1 / 2)
    round(q)
    print("q=(2*" + str(myList[0]) + "" + str(myList[1]) + ")/" + str(myList[3]) + "*1/2" +"= "+ 
str(q))
mylist=[]
item = int(input("Enter your Item to the List n1,n2,n3: "))
mylist.append(item)
sum(mylist)
```

and ım getting this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100,75,80'

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string and you can't parse the string to int when there is ','. You can use this to split numbers:

```
def sum (myList=[]):
for x in myList:
    q = float(((2 * myList[0] * myList[1]) / myList[3]) ** 1 / 2)
    round(q)
    print("q=(2*" + str(myList[0]) + "" + str(myList[1]) + ")/" + str(myList[3]) + "*1/2" +"= "+ 
str(q))
mylist=[]
item = list(map(int,input("Enter your Item to the List n1,n2,n3: ").split(','))
mylist.extend(item)
sum(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in handling the input.

`input()` reads an entire line as a string. If you want to pass three comma separated numbers, you could do something like:

```
mylist = [*map(int, input().split(','))]
```

your code would look something like:

```
def sum (myList):
    q = float(((2 * myList[0] * myList[1]) / myList[2]) ** 1 / 2)
    round(q)
    print("q=(2*" + str(myList[0]) + "" + str(myList[1]) + ")/" + str(myList[2]) + "**1/2" +"= "+  str(q))
mylist = [*map(int, input("Enter your Item to the List n1,n2,n3: ").split(','))]
sum(mylist)
```